# items, pieces, sets

Tags: grammar

Are there any rules which govern the choice between **items, pieces, sets**?

Which one is correct?

1) I have two pieces of advice/news. - I have two items of advice/news.

2) I have two sets of scales. - I have two pieces/items of scales?

Any logic behind it?

Comment: [*Let me give you a **piece** of advice*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Let+me+give+you+a+piece+of+advice%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Google Books says there are over 34,000 written instances of that (plus another 20,000 for [*Let me give you a **word** of advice*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Let+me+give+you+a+word+of+advice%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)). But whereas *a **set** of advice* and *an **item** of advice* are virtually unknown collocations, *a **set** of **scales*** is standard usage.

Comment: "Pieces" and "items" are pretty much interchangeable, but "sets" implies "groups" not "items".  Traditionally, a "set of scales" (when not talking about fish) includes the two trays, lever arm, fulcrum, and weight set, so it's a "set" (even when it morphs into a black electronic slab you stand on).  If not a "set of scales" the modern version is simply a "scale", with no "item" or "piece" associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

*"I have two scales,"* would be the first choice for item `2)`.

In item `1)`, **pieces** tends to connote some relationship between the **items**, e.g. **items** has a more general connotation and **items** may be unrelated other than for appearing in the same list.

Comment: I would tend to say *I have two sets of scales* - rather than *two scales*.

Answer (score 1):

Part of how people see the world is how they classify objects, and a place this turns up is in units of measure.  In some languages, there is an elaborate conventional system of numerical classifiers which become evident when people express quantities of various sorts of things.  Anthropologists have reported on such systems in languages of central and south America, for instance Quechua and Tzeltal.  It's not something I know much about, but you can find out more by looking for work on "numerical classifiers", "folk taxonomies", "Brent Berlin" (the anthropologist), "Paul Kay" (anthropologist and linguist).